# struct_ prefix vs no prefix

Tags: c, go, compilation, cgo

I'm currently writing some basic cgo code. According to the [cgo documention about Go to C references](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/):

> To access a struct, union, or enum type directly, prefix it with
>   struct_, union_, or enum_, as in C.struct_stat.

My understanding of this sentence is that if I have a struct named `Foo` in C, I have to use the type `C.struct_Foo` in Go.

I have written some Go code like:

```
package main

// #cgo LDFLAGS: -lnavilink -lserialport
// #cgo CFLAGS: -I/usr/local/include
// #include<navilink/navilink.h>
import "C"
import "errors"

func (d *Device) navilinkErrorToGoError() error {
    errorC := C.navilink_get_error_description(d.navilinkC)
    return errors.New(C.GoString(errorC))
    return nil
}

// Device représente une interface
// vers le port série connecté au GPS
type Device struct {
    navilinkC *C.struct_NavilinkDevice
}

// Open permettra au développeur d'ouvrir la communication
func (d *Device) Open(path string) error {
    res := C.navilink_open_device_from_name(C.CString(path), d.navilinkC)
    if res < 0 {
        return d.navilinkErrorToGoError()
    }
    return nil
}

// Close permettra au développeur de fermer la communication
func (d *Device) Close() {
    C.navilink_close_device(d.navilinkC)
}
```

I encounter a compilation error likes:

> cannot convert d.navilinkC (type *_Ctype_struct_NavilinkDevice) to
>   type _Ctype_struct___1

The definition of the C struct is the following:

```
typedef struct {
  struct sp_port* serial_port;
  struct sp_event_set* event_set;
  uint8_t buffer[NAVILINK_MAX_PACKET_SIZE];
  NavilinkInformation informations;
  int firmware_version;
  NavilinkPacket response_packet;
  int last_error_code;
} NavilinkDevice;
```

If I use `C.DeviceNavilink` instead of `C.DeviceNavilink` as the field's type, the compilation succeeds.

Every C functions expect a pointer to a `NavilinkDevice` C struct as last parameter. Code for the C library can be found [here](https://github.com/yageek/navilink)

Why does the upper documentation sentence mean since you can refer the C type without using any prefix? What is the difference between both?

Comment: Please make a [mcve]. If `Foo` is just a struct, then the `void will_allocate_foo(Foo *foo){` declaration isn't valid. This for example runs fine: https://play.golang.org/p/WSARkds3-ZE

Comment: I'm not sure to understand why is the C declaration invalid ?

Comment: If `Foo` is a named struct, then you must prepend the type with `struct`, as in my example.

Comment: I updated the provided code. In the original C source, I used a typedef and not a named struct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are declaring your C struct as a typedef and not as a named struct.

In your c code you have something like this:

```
typedef struct{
    int a;
    char *b;
    ...
    char z[20];
 }Foo;
```

In C you would refer to this as `Foo x` when declaring an instance of `Foo` so in Cgo you would refer to it as `C.Foo`.

The reason you are getting the weird error is because the compiler does not have a name for the struct you declared just a typedef, so it calls it `_0`.

In your example your Go code is expecting

```
struct Foo{
    int a;
    char *b;
    ...
    char z[20];
 };
```

In C you would refer to this as `struct Foo x` when declaring an instance of `Foo` so in Cgo you would refer to it as `C.struct_Foo`.

Extra Helpful Info

- If you need to get the size of a typedef struct Cgo use `C.sizeof_Foo`
- To see how Cgo declares the Go version of your C struct run `go tool cgo <go file>` and look at the `_obj/_cgo_gotypes.go` file

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. The cgo documentaion was not clear enough for me.